# Identify event when Outlook 2013 main window is shown (not loading screen)

Tags: c#, email, outlook, ms-office, vsto

I'm customizing Outlook UI by analyzing its child windows (smth like [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27262/Additional-custom-panel-in-Microsoft-Outlook) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871272/adding-a-section-to-the-to-do-bar-in-outlook-2007-2010/1911650#1911650)) and I have to do this as soon as Outlook main window is shown.

I receive Outlook main window handler by calling `Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle` in `OnStartupComplete` event handler. It must be working fine in Outlook 2007 and Outlook 2010, but 2013th shows splash screen first and only after that the main window with all Explorers and Inspectors. The problem is that in `OnStartupComplete` event occurs when this "splash screen" is being shown so I don't receive the right handler. 
I've tried some dirty hacks like:

  1. Signing Explorer `ViewSwitch` event.

  2. Ribbon `OnLoad` callback.

  3. Tab `getVisible` callback.

Unfortunately nothing helped. They all occur when the "splash screen" is being shown so `MainWindowHandle` points to it.

The question is if there is any way to define a trigger when `MainWindowHandle` will point to the Outlook's main window?

Comment: I dont think there is for the process - although waiting until the "mainwindow" title has text "Outlook" in it might work

Comment: It works fine if I execute this by clicking ribbon button (i.e. when OL main window is shown).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply cast an `Explorer` (`Application.ActiveExplorer`) or `Inspector` object to `IOleWindow` and call `IOleWindow::GetWindow`.

Answer (score 1):

I've investigated a bit more and found out that main Outlook window "rctrl_renwnd32" is created when splash screen is shown but it is invisible. Thus to get Outlook main window handle I use the following method

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string lclassName, IntPtr windowTitle);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int processId);

    public static IntPtr GetOutlookMainHWnd ()
    {
        int curtProcId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
        int wndProcId = 0;
        IntPtr olMainHWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
        while (curtProcId != wndProcId) //this is to ensure that we get main window of our own process
        {
            olMainHWnd = NativeMethods.FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, olMainHWnd, "rctrl_renwnd32", IntPtr.Zero);
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(olMainHWnd, out wndProcId);
        }

        return olMainHWnd;
    }
```